# Use a content file in visual studio C# project and let user modify it after project installation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

I am developing a plugin in visual studio C#.
I want to make use of a file which has some dictionary values
a=b
b=d and so on.
I created a content text file.
set Build - content 
    Copy - always

After plugin installation, the file gets copied to the target location.
If user modifies that file, application can't use the modified file, it still use the same old file which was present at the time of the project build.
Is there any way I can allow user to modify it and use it in the code.
File has to be present in build with default options and after installation, user should be able to modify.

I am Using visual studio 2017.

Comment: How are you referencing the "context file"? Just reading at runtime, or embedded resource.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are calling/accessing this file, but I remember when i did VS Exension developement that you'd need to restart the IDE in order to see changes from external files since VS caches it for you.